# How do I fix this AngularJS error: Can't find variable: $interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
moduleT1.controller('SessionClock', function ($scope) {
    $interval(wtf, 5000);
});
```

From the error console:

```
Error: Can't find variable: $interval
```

I am using AngularJS 1.3.14. Setting `$scope` variables in the controller and data-binding them in the html works fine, until I add an `$interval` or `$timeout` line into the controller and get this error. What's going on?

Comment: You need to inject it `moduleT1.controller('SessionClock', function ($scope, $interval) {`.. Worth looking at the basic angular documentation, i'd suggest

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by injecting? I just want a simple timer for my data-binding. Thanks

Comment: Injection is one of the key points of Angular, it's how you can create shared services / modules and only use them when you need them.

Comment: Thanks tymeJV. Still a noob with Angular.

Comment: @paulwal222 Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), this should help!! Dependency Injection is not just a key point of angular itself, it makes up one of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles - `D`. For example you could get an instance of `$interval` without need to inject as well. `var $interval = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$interval')` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
moduleT1.controller('SessionClock', [ '$scope','$interval', function ($scope,$interval) {
    $interval(wtf, 5000);
}]);
```

This should solve your problem. Just make sure you have the same order in the injector and function().